# large arithmetic progression modulo p (II)

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

Is it possible to construct a $B$ $\subseteq$ $Z_p(=Z/pZ)$ of cardinal $cp^{\frac{1}{3}}$, for some constant $c$, such that there exists an arithmetic progression of size $c_1p^{\frac{2}{3}}$, for some constant $c_1$, inside $B+αB$ for any $\alpha\in Z_p$?

Comment: What is wrong with taking $B$ to be an arithmetic progression of size $cp^ {1/3}$?

Comment: @js21 $B+B$ will then have size around $2cp^{1/3}$.

Comment: Oh, I misread the exponent $2/3$.